# How can I fill a listView with the titles of the files in Assets?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a Lyrics menu option in an app I started to develop in Xamarin Android. When it's clicked, it starts a new activity called Lyrics, in there is a listView that should be populated with clickable rows that have the titles of the txt files inside the Assets folder.

So if there were 3 lyricsX.txt files in the Assets folder, the listView would look something like this:

```
[ lyrics1.txt ]
[ lyrics2.txt ]
[ lyrics3.txt ]
```

And these buttons with the lyrics titles should be clickable.

I have tried to put the path into a string file and then use Directory.EnumerateFiles .. then foreach through that and write the result to the debug console, but nothing gets logged. Probably I have the wrong approach, I just don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

```
[Activity(Label = "Lyrics")]
    public class Lyrics : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            string assetsPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;
            var assetsContents = Directory.EnumerateFiles(assetsPath);
            TextView title = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lyricsTitle);

            foreach(var fileName in assetsContents)
            {
                Log.Debug("debug", "NAME:" + fileName);
            }

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.lyrics);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here you go... this will show you how to access files from the Assets folder as well as a way to load them in a ListView with clickable results.

**main_layout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvAssetFiles"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Widget;

namespace ListViewExample {

    [Activity(Label = "ListView Example", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity {

        private ListView lvFiles;
        private List<string> lstFiles = new List<string>();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_layout);

            // To get all .txt files in the Assets root folder...
            var listAssets = Assets.List("");
            foreach (var file in listAssets) {
                if (file.EndsWith(".txt"))
                    lstFiles.Add(file);
            }

            // To get all files in the Assets/Lyrics folder...
            //listAssets = Assets.List("Lyrics");
            //foreach (var file in listAssets)
            //    lstFiles.Add(file);

            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, lstFiles.ToArray());
            // Or, use this to keep the item highlighted after clicking
            //var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1, lstFiles.ToArray());
            lvFiles = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvAssetFiles);
            lvFiles.Adapter = adapter;
            lvFiles.ItemClick += lvFiles_ItemClick;
            lvFiles.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
        }

        private void lvFiles_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
            var sItemSelected = lstFiles[e.Position];
            Android.Util.Log.Info("MyApp", $"Item Selected: {sItemSelected}");
        }

    }
}
```

Also, be sure each of your files in the Assets folder are set to "AndroidAsset" for the "Build Action".

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out first thing in the morning.

Comment: Bruce, I really appreciate the help and the effort. I have sent a connect request on Linked-in. I have been heavily suffering with Xamarin for a very long time, and I would really appreciate it if you could help me out to any extent (I don't mean for free, although my wallet has limits).